# Pandas join Value error Shape of passed Value inconsistent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to join two dataframe using `pd.join`

My two dataset, frame1 is like

```
512      -1.000000
335      30.066667
1092      0.033333
1811      0.450000
6106     -1.000000
       ...
10651    -1.000000
10659    -1.000000
10660     0.000000
10663     0.050000
10677    -1.000000
Name: time_difference_Backward, Length: 951, dtype: float64
```

The frame2 is of shape `[10678 rows x 13 columns]`

I'm trying two join these two dataframes on their `index` and add a new column to the frame2

I have the following code

```
frame3 = frame1.join(frame2, how='left')
```

but the error says

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (954, 1), indices imply (951, 1)
```

What could be the potential reason for this issue ?

I tried to use `pd.concat(axis=1)` and I get the same error

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add frame1 as an extra column to frame2?

```
frame2['time_difference_Backward'] = frame1
```

Comment: I tried it and it shows ```ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis```, does it mean my frame has duplicate index ? I tried to check duplication using ```duplicated()``` and it gives me ```ValueError: Length of passed values is 954, index implies 951.``` again

Comment: does frame2 have another columns named `time_difference_Backward` ?

Comment: and can I get a head from frame1?

Comment: and can you also check to see if 
`len(frame1.index) == len(set(frame1.index)`

this will check to see if there are duplicates in your index.  that could cause some issues.  same with frame2

Comment: I checked that, ```len(frame1.index) = 951```, ```len(set(frame1.index)) = 950```, is there a way to eliminate those duplicate index ?

Comment: do these index values matter?  if not, you could just set `frame1.index = range(0, len(frame1)`

Comment: yeah, I dropped those duplicate index  using ```backward_difference.index.drop_duplicates()```, and it works, Thank you!

Comment: sure.  just be careful and realize that drop_duplicates will drop an entire row.  if you're fine with this, though, then that solution should work :)